# Contantly updating textview in a custom cursor adapter

Tags: android, simplecursoradapter, android-cursoradapter, timeline

I have a

1. TimelineViewActivity class, contains a listView
2. TimelineFeedsCursorAdapter class, extends the CursorAdapter

Here, in this adapter class I am fetching the rows from SQLite db and populating the list.

Now in each list item there is a time specifying when was the timeline feed created i.e. 2 hours ago or 10 hours ago, etc.

How can I update the time TextView constantly using a Handler and postDelay() function from TimelineViewActivity class so that I don't have to refresh each item all the time, just like in Facebook app - the timeline posts.

Comment: Why don't you want to refresh all the items ? Create your handler to repeat every minute (or more) and call NotifyDatasetChanged(). It will in fact refresh everything but the list will still be scrolled, the user might not even notice the refresh.

Comment: Hey Stephane, actually I just want to update the duration of the post. I have added the notifyDataSetChanged() method invocation when there is a DB transaction. This is the case where user is ideal or scrolling the Timeline ListView and no such new post has been added. I am just updating the duration of the post. Tell me if question is not so clear I will try to explain it is different way using code blocks.

Comment: I understand, but refreshing the list once a minute is really not a big deal. Refresh everything and it's good. The views will be recycled, even if the user is currently scrolling he might not notice that the data has changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't use `Handler`. When using `CursorAdapter` with db integration best thing to do is to implements `LoaderCallbacks<Cursor>` which will give you callback on every database changes.
you will need to initiate the callback on your `onCreate` method like this: `getLoaderManager().initLoader(0, null, this);`

Now the fun part:
when implementing `LoaderCallbacks<Cursor>` you will forced to override three methods:

first method will be called once and create the loader. when creating the loader, you specifying which columns you want to receive on each database change:

```
        @Override
    public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {
        CursorLoader loader = new CursorLoader(getActivity(), DataProvider.CONTENT_URI_MESSAGES, new String[] {
                DataProvider.COL_ID, DataProvider.COL_NAME, DataProvider.COL_DATE }, null, null, DataProvider.COL_DATE
                + " DESC");
        return loader;
    }
```

second method will be called when the loader will created and on every database change on the loader table (I think this is what you looking for):

```
        @Override
    public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor data) {
        Log.i("");
        adapter.swapCursor(data);
    }
```

the last methode will be called when the loader rest itself:

```
        @Override
    public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> loader) {
        adapter.swapCursor(null);
    }
```

Visit http://developer.android.com/guide/components/loaders.html for more information.

EDIT:
try use the code from within your adapter:

```
@Override
        public void setViewText(TextView textView, String text) {

            if(textView.getId() == R.id.tv_time_past) {
                 long creation_date = 0;
                 if (text.matches("[0-9]+") && text.length() > 2)                   
                     creation_date = Long.parseLong();
                 if(creation_date > 0)
                     new DateSetter(textView, creation_date );

            }
}
```

code for DateSetter thread:

```
   private class DateSetter extends Thread{

    private TextView textView;
    private long creation_date;

    public DateSetter(TextView textView, long creation_date){
        this.textView = textView;
        this.creation_date = creation_date;
    }

    @Override
    public synchronized void run() {
        while (mRunning) {
            String datePast = getTimePastAsString(System.currentTimeMillis(), creation_date);
            Long.parseLong()
            textView.setText(datePast);
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);// update every 1 seconds
            } catch(Exception e){};
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you friend, I will optimize my code as per your suggestion. But sorry I can't accept this as an answer as because your solution is for the situation when there is a transaction at DB end and want to reflect the change on View end.

Comment: In my scenario, I am picking up the creation_date of the post and doing a calculation i.e. System.currentTimeMillis - creation_date in timemillis and then showing the duration of the post. With time I want to keep updating the duration, say after each 10 seconds like 59 minutes ago becomes 1 hour ago after 1 minute. I can't figure out how to accomplish it.

Comment: @raivikrant1 have you try doing it from the adapter? you can do it from setViewText(TextView textView, String text). check if the textView have the same id as the Date text view and create thread with the text view and the creation_date and do the work in there inside a while(mRunning) method which you stop with setting mRunning to false on onDestroy

Comment: Thank you :-) I am a fool, I should have thought a bit more, I have done this in my DialogFragments to set callbacks or imageView bitmaps.. Thank you, I will surely try this now..